# How to prevent a literal type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a class like this which wraps over a value:

```
class Data<T> {
  constructor(public val: T){}

  set(newVal: T) {
    this.val = newVal;
  }
}

const a = new Data('hello');
a.set('world');
// typeof a --> Primitive<string>
```

So far so good, but now I want to restrict it to only one of a set of types, let's say the primitives:

```
type Primitives = boolean|string|number|null|undefined;

class PrimitiveData<T extends Primitives> {
  constructor(public val: T){}

  set(newVal: T) {
    this.val = newVal;
  }
}

const b = new PrimitiveData('hello');
b.set('world'); // Error :(
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Data%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(public%20val%3A%20T)%7B%7D%0A%0A%20%20set(newVal%3A%20T)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.val%20%3D%20newVal%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20new%20Data('hello')%3B%0Aa.set('world')%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0A%0Atype%20Primitives%20%3D%20boolean%7Cstring%7Cnumber%7Cnull%7Cundefined%3B%0A%0Aclass%20PrimitiveData%3CT%20extends%20Primitives%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(public%20val%3A%20T)%7B%7D%0A%0A%20%20set(newVal%3A%20T)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.val%20%3D%20newVal%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20new%20PrimitiveData('hello')%3B%0Ab.set('world')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%20%3A(%0A)

That last line fails because `b` is a `Primitive<'hello'>` not a `Primitive<string>`, and so `set` will only take the literal `'hello'` as a value, which clearly isn't what I'm after.

What am I doing wrong here? Without resorting to explicitly widening the types myself (eg: `new Primitive<string>('hello')`) is there anything I can do?

Comment: You can use a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to widen literals; I might write that up if nobody else does before I get to it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TypeScript [intentionally infers literal types just about everywhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676), but usually widens those types except in a few circumstances.  One is when you have a type parameter which `extends` one of the widened types.  The heuristic is that if you're asking for `T extends string` you might care to keep the exact literal.  This is still true with unions, like `T extends Primitives`, so you get this behavior.

We can use [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to force (unions of) string, number, and boolean literals to widen to (unions of) `string`, `number`, and `boolean`:

```
type WidenLiterals<T> = 
  T extends boolean ? boolean :
  T extends string ? string : 
  T extends number ? number : 
  T;

type WString = WidenLiterals<"hello"> // string
type WNumber = WidenLiterals<123> // number
type WBooleanOrUndefined = WidenLiterals<true | undefined> // boolean | undefined
```

Now this is great, and one way you might want to proceed is to use `WidenLiterals<T>` in place of `T` everywhere inside `PrimitiveData`:

```
class PrimitiveDataTest<T extends Primitives> {
  constructor(public val: WidenLiterals<T>){}
  set(newVal: WidenLiterals<T>) {
    this.val = newVal;
  }
}

const bTest = new PrimitiveDataTest("hello"); // PrimitiveDataTest<"hello">
bTest.set("world"); // okay
```

And that works as far as it goes. `bTest` is of type `PrimitiveDataTest<"hello">`, but the actual type of `val` is `string` and you can use it as such.  Unfortunately, you get this undesirable behavior:

```
let aTest = new PrimitiveDataTest("goodbye"); // PrimitiveDataTest<"goodbye">
aTest = bTest; // error! 
// PrimitiveDataTest<"hello"> not assignable to PrimitiveDataTest<"goodbye">.
// Type '"hello"' is not assignable to type '"goodbye"'.
```

This seems to be due to a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31295) in TypeScript where conditional types are not being checked properly.  The types `PrimitiveDataTest<"hello">` and `PrimitiveDataTest<"goodbye">` are each [structurally identical to](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) each other and to `PrimitiveDataTest<string>`, so the types should be mutually assignable.  That they are not is a bug which may or may not get addressed in the near future (maybe some fixes are set for TS3.5 or TS3.6?)

If that's okay then you can probably stop there.

---

Otherwise, you might consider this implementation, instead. Define an unconstrained version like `Data<T>`:

```
class Data<T> {
  constructor(public val: T) {}
  set(newVal: T) {
    this.val = newVal;
  }
}
```

And then define the type and value `PrimitiveData` as related to `Data` like this:

```
interface PrimitiveData<T extends Primitives> extends Data<T> {}
const PrimitiveData = Data as new <T extends Primitives>(
  val: T
) => PrimitiveData<WidenLiterals<T>>;
```

The pair of type and value named `PrimitiveData` acts like a generic class where `T` is constrained to `Primitives`, but when you call the constructor the resulting instance is of the widened type:

```
const b = new PrimitiveData("hello"); // PrimitiveData<string>
b.set("world"); // okay
let a = new PrimitiveData("goodbye"); // PrimitiveData<string>
a = b; // okay
```

That might be easier for users of `PrimitiveData` to work with, although the implementation of `PrimitiveData` does require a bit of hoop jumping.

---

Okay, hope that helps you move forward.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glgEwgOwDJ2BATgQwDYDOAPACoB8UAvFCVBAB6bIIFQBGA9h3hDsgFBQoAfnZcefQVABcNOoxQsoBYFjjIA5iOWr1W2bQZMlyAK4BbNtm1nL1gwG5+-UJFgBlXZqqxEKdJi4hEQARAAWEHh4HCFkDlAA9Ak6apou4NAwAHIWVlg+8EhoGNj4xACMAEwAzHGJybZ56W4wAELivMgA8lgAqswQAGbqEAgFfsWBZUSqptAAPlCmA8PIo3VJYtydUIvLSKujzq7QAApq5hhwAG4QrNSc23zzKqka843YH6ZR8-tDIwQTn4AGM8DgCKxznBLsAbhAACI4YA4Eh3YCkeTGKEXK63AgUADeUhBHGQr1MIOAHCwAAowKY2Hg4CCoNd8LJCv4SkFiOQAJSEgC+UgIEGAtLWAHcAGoc3xFAKlYICqDEoRCYBhOAEAB07LwPmlcrwTiEIpFoLJKnYaJt1GlUGhsPhSJRdol4Ui0RC-Pim2deMRyNR6NCESiMTI-DYHt1Ys9UppeAQvv9yQ4AGscCBnJsGCCIGBgFAtTr+DwS6H7VBHYG4bc3dXPRouAg2CAIGn6k7cQ3g+6wyFWxx253Yvxmz5Y+j03QsFgaQBCKD8AN910hj3h71R2scKuQuAaZA4JnQam9mFBpvb4dtjtdsi6tfJEgZKAAci9kZCn6gOr7oeBDHqe56lhwpYft+I5jl2n4vs4YIQqwTakESJLWrMVI0vSjLMqyBoGPyaoikICaShAsryiQJHqhqZZ6gaRpUSaZpQBazjqIEgw4IWV4uo2IaYkYig4te-YEliYlQGh5CkVa5IlvWm4oj4TZQBCtZUVAIkKMw4mCXcZC0lIRE0PwJGUBQKlCSiRBcpMyp8mQcRIVh7AsVKAk3iGtI-j6fo9rZA44EQrx6NGbDxuK-lJlgKbdpsWY5hW4qaV5Pn9k2-mwY+SXJCFaERZo0Y4NOc4pSAQA)

Comment: You definitely delivered on the offer to 'write that up'. :) Excellent information and explanation here, thank you!