# How can I make a typescript generic less specific?

Tags: typescript, generics

When typescript captures generics it captures them very specifically which can lead to complications.

How can I make this "LessSpecific" type dynamically return the less specific type of the provided argument?

```js
const value: LessSpecific<'I am a string literal!'>
// Expected type of value: string
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Widen a type with a type generic in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355418/widen-a-type-with-a-type-generic-in-typescript)

Comment: @TobiasS. I was looking for a more dynamic way to convert the type that doesn't require hardcoding every edge case but if this is the only way then yes.

Comment: Aren't there only the three cases for `string` `number` and `boolean` ?

Comment: No, there would be more cases for like arrays, objects, ect.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp9VBW) work for you?