# Typescript: how to type Record values specifically based on their key?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I am trying to build a type that allows me to have a string key with a value within the union `string | number | boolean`:

```
type FilterKey = string;
type FilterValue = string | number | boolean;
type Filters<K extends FilterKey, T extends FilterValue> = Record<K, T>;
```

However, I'd like to be able to have the compiler infer the proper type of the value when accessing it by key. I'm a little stuck, and I've gotten to a type that looks like this which feels close:

```
type FilterKey = string;
type FilterValue = string | number | boolean;
type Filters<V extends FilterValue, T extends Record<FilterKey, V>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};
```

This is as close as I have gotten, however I can see that if I try to access a specific property within the record such as this:

```
function useFilters<V extends FilterValue, T extends Record<FilterKey, V>>(initialValue: Filters<V, T>) {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(initialValue)
  // Other logic not relevant to this, but the return type is the same as the initial value
  return filters;
}

const filters = buildFilters({ search: "", active: true });

// The type should be string, but the type assertion is the specific value of ""
filters.search

// Should be boolean, but is asserted as 'true'
filters.active
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but is there a way to type a record so that the value type is inferred based on the key provided, assuming there is an 'initial' object that provides the structure?

Comment: It may work with  `satisfies Record<string, string | number | boolean`.That enforces that your structure is a record but you still get the correct type for each when accessing each of its keys.

Comment: So is your question really just *two* questions? We don't really do multiple questions in one on Stack Overflow, so could you edit the post to make it clear what specifically you are having trouble with? You can always just ask another question if you have multiple problems.

Comment: I can edit, inferring what types come from the first part is more important and will hopefully give me clues as for how to solve the second part

Comment: I think you should just change the return type to map over the given type and widen its values.

Comment: Is `buildFilters` same as `useFilters`? And does typecasting solve your problem?

`const filters = buildFilters({ search: "" as string, active: true as boolean});`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to catch the narrow types and [then widen them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355418/widen-a-type-with-a-type-generic-in-typescript) back out.

For example:

```
type WidenToPrimitive<T extends string | number | boolean> =
  T extends string ? string :
  T extends number ? number :
  T extends boolean ? boolean :
  T;

type Test = WidenToPrimitive<'a'> // string
```

This type checks to see if `T` extends a non literal type, and if it does, then it resolves to that non literal type.

No just use that on the value that needs widening:

```
type FilterKey = string;
type FilterValue = string | number | boolean;
type Filters<V extends FilterValue, T extends Record<FilterKey, V>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: WidenToPrimitive<T[P]>;
};
```

And the rest works as you expect:

```
function useFilters<V extends FilterValue, T extends Record<FilterKey, V>>(initialValue: Filters<V, T>) {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState(initialValue)
  // Other logic not relevant to this, but the return type is the same as the initial value
  return filters;
}

const filters = useFilters({ search: "", active: true });

filters.search // string
filters.active // boolean
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVAUMzAJ5gEDqwAJugB2AFQgAFKKGAxgAN3QAeYXHQAPfIL6o4qGJMEBzOAB84g5CABG6KCbiWIEADZ1BAPjgBeZnDjK1Glo6esCGcAD8wfpGAFw+firqQkHmVjYRZhbWtnG+-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)