# More elegant solution to widen a type with a type generic in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function that should get the widened type of the default parameter if one is provided, otherwise the type must be `any`.

```
export const get = <TDefault = unknown>(value: object, path: string, defaultValue?: TDefault){
  //...
}
```

The type of the function is restricted to the litteral type of the default value when one is provided, which is not what I want.
The below code solves the problem, but is far from elegant.
Is there a more elegant solution to widen the type of the default value ?

```
export type ToPrimitive<T> = 
  T extends string
  ? string
  : T extends number
  ? number
  : T extends boolean
  ? boolean
  : T extends undefined
  ? object
  : keyof T extends never
  ? object
  : T extends object
  ? T
  : any

export const get = <TDefault = unknown>(value: object, path: string, defaultValue?: TDefault): ToPrimitive<TDefault>{
  //...
}
```

Found the current solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355418/widen-a-type-with-a-type-generic-in-typescript)

Comment: "The type of the function is restricted to the litteral type of the default value" - I don't see that... https://tsplay.dev/wEjvZN

Comment: @merryweather, in your example the type of defaultValue is inferred as `0` instead of `number`.  That is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve.  The `0` must be widened to `number`

Comment: ...What? It literally isn't. The ^? reveals "defaultValue?: number | undefined".

Comment: No it doesn't, add `return defaultValue` in the function in your playground example, then hover over `num`.  Typescript will reveal `const num: 0 | undefined`
not `const num: number | undefined`