# How to create an object type from tuple of objects?

Tags: typescript, tuples, mapped-types

From this data structure :

```js
const properties = [
  { name: 'name', type: '' },
  { name: 'age', type: 0 },
  { name: 'sex', type: ['m', 'f'] as const },
  { name: 'username', type: '' }
]
```

I am trying to construct -dynamically- the following type :

```js
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  sex: 'm'|'f';
  username: string;
}
```

I know TypeScript has the means to create types by mapping other types. But here the source Object is an Array so it seems a little bit tricky. How would I do that?

Comment: I think that you will have to write a script that transforms a `properties` array into a type declaration and put it in a .d.ts file.

Answer (score 7):

A mapped type is indeed the way to go. To ensure no types get widened you will have to add `as const` to `properties`:

```
const properties = [
  { name: 'name', type: '' },
  { name: 'age', type: 0 },
  { name: 'sex', type: ['m', 'f'] as const },
  { name: 'username', type: '' }
] as const
```

You can then use a mapped type in which you remap the keys from array indices to the property names and map the values to the types. The mapped type itself looks like this:

```
type FromProperties<P extends readonly unknown[]> = {
  [K in IndexKeys<P> as Name<P[K]>]: Type<P[K]>
}
```

It maps over the keys that are actual indices (`'0'`, `'1'`, etc.) rather than array properties, remaps the key to the property `name`, and has `Type<P[K]>` as the value.

To get the proper index keys, you can exclude the properties on `[]` from your array, so only the indices will be left:

```
type IndexKeys<A extends readonly unknown[]> = Exclude<keyof A, keyof []>
```

To get the name, a simple conditional type can be used:

```
type Name<O> = O extends { name: infer N } ? N extends string ? N : never : never
```

And to determine the actual type for each `type` value, you can use a slightly more complicated conditional type:

```
type Type<O> = 
  O extends { type: infer T }
  ?   T extends number ? number 
    : T extends string ? string 
    : T extends readonly unknown[] ? T[number]
    : never // `name` property is not a number, string or array
  : never // object has no `type` property
```

The extends clauses are to prevent inferring types that are too narrow (e.g. `''` instead of `string`) and to infer the union type for arrays. You can add more types if needed.

With these definitions, `Properties` can be constructed with

```
type Person = FromProperties<typeof properties>
// Inferred type:
// type Person = {
//     name: string;
//     age: number;
//     sex: "m" | "f";
//     username: string;
// }
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxHApgqBLFEYF4YDaAUDDAN4xgCGAtigFwwDk1dTANDFAJ6qNNMYAX3YlylWg2ZUA5ig5deUgAzDRpCqylMIKAB4KefQkxoKmAMyYBdGFRyhIsEWM2T%20AV10Ithpf0EhIlt7GEdoIiIjFBgASTAAE30AaRRuCAAeAEEYfSgURJwEFCoE8AAbbhgPMABrMBAAdzACawA%20PBgAUT1gco8kjNq0kAsYLM5h7lHCdsjomAA5SQyAeQ78Vdy9fMLxLUYMMAs0JeEYAH4zvIKEnGgEI5lLs8YwFAA3U7fPtHmlGAAFSUaw2MDEWxuewo0UOx1OgOEYiupERULulA8NAARqcrmAsbiEODSKRGGidrd7lBHmBnlcHk8SaTydtdhjiqUKlUavUmi1bFdAQQCTi0NYxGTKL9iQB6WUwAAGWkV8CQqHQVQwOAasComLFCE4jLpMBAxKoCAQVG4Yh%20XzlCpA2IAVihgLAABahBpK6KqxDINA8f6oGAAMSQNAACurg1hMtG2VSYJyymBKtU6g1mq0wWQxARkjAjnFEik0omOqFlnQMtGi%201rOSQQ3knMhOCogDo2gIOBOpGQDG4%20gExlojNAxrMNg2kR5WWTlaUAlFHwFwqFr2EP2wJ0C4vSRI6IwTTIANyb492ORvQloK9H0m6PSMABENHfMAAPjB3xY75Pgqx5eGgBwwOewHCEAA)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not that hard. All you need is a mapped type with keys remapped to the type of the `name` property of the tuple members (which can be done very nicely with [key remapping since 4.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)) and values to the `type` property of corresponding members.

First, you need to let the compiler know the `properties` array is actually a tuple with an `as const` assertion:

```ts
const properties = [
  { name: 'name', type: '' },
  { name: 'age', type: 0 },
  { name: 'sex', type: ['m', 'f'] as const },
  { name: 'username', type: '' }
] as const;
```

Next, let's make the type reusable by defining a generic type able to operate on arbitrary properties of the members of the tuple. First, we need to extract indices to be able to map
members to properties one-to-one. This is done via `Exclude<keyof T, keyof readonly any[]>` (leaves indices only).

We can use the resulting union of indices to do the mapping:

```ts
type TupleToProps<T extends readonly any[], VP extends keyof T[number], VV extends keyof T[number]> = {
    [ P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof readonly any[]> as T[P][VP] & string ] : T[P][VV] 
};
```

`VP` and `VV` ensure the utility type can work with any homogenous tuple of objects and `& string` leaves only string-compatible properties. This already yields us a pretty nice result:

```ts
type PersonTest = TupleToProps<typeof properties, "name", "type">;
/**
 * type PersonTest = {
 *  name: "";
 *  age: 0;
 *  sex: readonly ["m", "f"];
 *  username: "";
 * }
 */
```

After that, this is only a matter of cosmetic changes: extracting values from tuple-like types and widening literal ones (courtesy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59355670/11407695) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56333836/11407695) Q&A with a small upgrade to exclude keys that should not be widened):

```ts
type ToPrimitive<T> =
  T extends string ? string
  : T extends number ? number
  : T extends boolean ? boolean
  : T;
// mapped types which will preserve keys with more wide value types
type Widen<O, E = never> = {
  [K in keyof O]: K extends E ? O[K] : ToPrimitive<O[K]>
}

type TupleToPropsTwo<T extends readonly any[], VP extends keyof T[number], VV extends keyof T[number], E extends T[number][VP]> = Widen<{
    [ P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof readonly any[]> as T[P][VP] & string ] : T[P][VV] extends readonly any[] ? T[P][VV][number] : T[P][VV]
}, E>;

type PersonTest2 = TupleToPropsTwo<typeof properties, "name", "type", "sex">;
/**
 * type PersonTest2 = {
 *  name: string;
 *  age: number;
 *  sex: "m" | "f";
 *  username: string;
 * }
 */
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=44&ssc=4&pln=22&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxHApgqBLFEYF4YDaAUDDAN4xgCGAtigFwwDk1dTANDFAJ6qNNMYAX3YlylWg2ZUA5ig5deUgAzDRpCqylMIKAB4KefQkxoKmAMyYBdGFRyhIsEWM2T%20AV10Ithpf0EhIlt7GEdoAG4iIiMUGAAVDzgAGxR4kAAFJDgIAHkwFAAeeJh9KBQwABMcBBQqSvBk7jswbgJrTgA1DNK9cqqcAGsUbhALBIIwDxoAIzQOmE7O3v7qmGHR8fjJ6bmEawA%20PHIxUgIYHowwGABRPWBkj0qijbGEzlfx2vrG5qpW9pHULbDLWAjdWwAMhg0AQVxkMFsjBBYKWtiIQiiMSUFzQEHA8WwUAAjMdEik0plsnkCoVYm9EMg0JhsJwAERaNns2Jsg5RAD0ACpBSRBYpULiEPiwIToKT8GRRaQtIw2WyojAxXY5IxlBqtbo9Ixvg0wE1CGyaFyYGyLGzrPrSF40CqbeqlUFNfzorEElSMDQMJgAG5FeJHXBiEplCprWHwmAAfhhUDhYBkYmRK1jOCmszQScouzQmYS2YGMBmIBAqX%20harNbqYFL8QF-JgNCocFQlXF2BgAHcABYYYBDwcYZLJeC1byh9YjHADoPjmggWoT54wYNUR5xWIQbESgDqGGeYEKuU4N2OBVDCAjJzOAGkYFcF5sYLlrIxXzGKzeya5AQz5In6WQBkGGChpeIGHBiPo4uSqTpFkyAQPEA4gMU5ZrCavwtG0CzdLhQwjG82x5nsxHLP%20ayfBMVHzNepGMcW%20zgqCj6nuehSKqQZwXG%201x3A8TwvORWwfJJMD4WafwAocdg4CinFQimaYImBqloqxcnmv8RGFjpnRgkx%20wwMiBCguCpkYtefKIRKGR4gSRIAExkkkKFUuhmHYfS4yMqg6BYBA7KctySjWmyhq8gKwpKr6LlSm50CeQqSoSHQjDxumjralI5kFYaqpWjAAA%20Np2gVzo%20O4Gnwo6nqCt6R5xCl0rHPx2VSHlMgaoVjDFWIpXMGYFWWEwg11a6-VREIQA)