# Wrong automatic return type deduction in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In a settings class I have a method to get a value, with an optional default value to return if the given key cannot be found:

```js
    /**
     * Returns the value stored at the given key, which can have the form `qualifier.subKey`.
     *
     * @param key The key to look up.
     * @param defaultValue An optional value to be returned if the there's no value at the given key or the key doesn't
     *                     exist at all.
     *
     * @returns If a return value is given the return type is the same as that of the default value. Otherwise it's
     *          either undefined or the same as the type found at the given key.
     */
    public get<T>(key: string, defaultValue: T): T;
    public get(key: string): any;
    public get<T>(key: string, defaultValue?: T): T | undefined {
        const { target, subKey } = this.objectForKey(key, false);
        if (!target || !subKey) {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        return target[subKey] as T ?? defaultValue;
    }
```

This implementation gives me return types I did not expect. Consider this call:

```js
const removeIdleTime = settings.get("workers.removeIdleTime", 60);
```

The variable `removeIdleTime` is not of type number as I would expect, but of type `60`. I can explicitly use `<number>` as template/generic parameter to `get` and the result will then be ok, but it would be way more cool to have Typescript deduce the right type. What must be changed to accomplish that?

### Update

I just found the description about [type widening](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/literal-type-widening-in-typescript) in Typescript (I didn't know the correct term at the time of writing this question). It turns out that the type is widended when assigning the result of `get` to a mutable variable. Otherwise it stays a literal type.

While this is interesting information, it doesn't help with this question, because linters will usually convert any `let` to `const` if they are not changed after the initial assignment.

Comment: Are the keys a finite set of values?  If so then you would want the generic to be K extends keyof SomeType where the key is K and the defaultValue is SomeType[K].

Comment: But which type could SomeType be, given that e.g. number, string, boolean don't have a common ancestor?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but is the crux of the issue here the question how to go from a literal type (`60`) to a basic type (`number`)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wonder why a literal type is used at all. Who would expect a literal type in such a context?

Comment: SomeType would be the type of the target object.  But I don’t know enough about your class to understand what the valid keys are or how we map from keys to values.

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou Uhm, you didn't change or simplify much, just added a bit surrounding code. The question is still the same. The return type of the `get` method is the literal type 60, while I would expect `number` as return type. As easy as that.

Comment: @LindaPaiste which target object do you mean? The container for the values is a nested map, which can hold anything, from objects through base types like strings or numbers. The valid keys are always strings, but that doesn't matter here. What only matters is the generic parameter T, which I can either specify explicitly or let Typescript infer from the default value (if that is given).

Comment: Interesting, not sure in which version this changed, but previously to "trigger" literal type inference you had to have primitive type in generic type constraint https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24310. But that's not the case anymore https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMAeAFQD4AKADwC54yBKBsgbgCgOw8BnDJDhzwAvIWJUAbAAYmbIA

Comment: Yes, I want to have the widended type (here number) for the literal 60. By widended type I refer to the Github PR @AlekseyL. posted above, which exactly addresses my issue.

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but I would recommend checking out [How to prevent a literal type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56332310/1470607) and [Widen a type with a type generic in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59355418/1470607), they're both on similar topics. Also, it wouldn't hurt to file a bug report on Typescript's Github to get an authoritative response to this — it used to work in the past, it isn't clear if the change was intentional or not.

Comment: @Etheryte No need to file a bug report. The behavior change is intended. See the links from Aleksey, where Anders explains the rationale behind that.

Comment: If it is indeed a `const`, then I don't see any significant downside to having its type be `60` instead of `number`.

Comment: There are cases where it is a problem: imagine you get a number value from storage and use the default one. The literal type is then 1 and when you test it for 2 you'll get a warning that this comparison is always false, because 1 and 2 have no overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Thanks to @Etheryte I found a solution: there's a way to enforce type widening by using conditional types.

```
export type ValueType<T> = T extends string
    ? string
    : T extends number
        ? number
        : T extends boolean
            ? boolean
            : T extends undefined
                ? undefined
                : [T] extends [any]
                    ? T
                    : object;
```

which can be used so (note the only change, for the return type):

```js
    /**
     * Returns the value stored at the given key, which can have the form `qualifier.subKey`.
     *
     * @param key The key to look up.
     * @param defaultValue An optional value to be returned if the there's no value at the given key or the key doesn't
     *                     exist at all.
     *
     * @returns If a return value is given the return type is the same as that of the default value. Otherwise it's
     *          either undefined or the same as the type found at the given key.
     */
    public get<T>(key: string, defaultValue: T): ValueType<T>;
    public get(key: string): any;
    public get<T>(key: string, defaultValue?: T): T | undefined {
        const { target, subKey } = this.objectForKey(key, false);
        if (!target || !subKey) {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        return target[subKey] as T ?? defaultValue;
    }
```

This also works for enums, where the conditional type returns number or string, depending on the base type of the enum.

---

### Previous Answer

This behavior is by design. Literal values that are assigned to constant targets keep their literal type. This follows the principle of always storing the most narrow type. In situations where values can be changed (e.g. by assigning a literal to a mutable variable) the Typescript transpiler widens the type to allow for other values than the initial literal. You can read a bit more about that in the article [Literal Type Widening in TypeScript](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/literal-type-widening-in-typescript).

There's no way (I know of) to force type widening, so I see 3 possible ways here:

1. Use a mutable target when you assign the result from the `get` call. This might be problematic, because linters will try to "optimize" the variable to become immutable, if there are no other assignments to it.
2. Add an explicit type annotation to the target, like:

`const removeIdleTime: number = settings.get("workers.removeIdleTime", 60);`

3. Specify the generic parameter explicitly:

`const removeIdleTime = settings.get<number>("workers.removeIdleTime", 60);`

or

`const removeIdleTime = settings.get("workers.removeIdleTime", 60 as number);`

All these ways are not really a solution to my question, though.